# Why my udev rule does not work in my Fedora PC?

Tags: udev

I would like to call a script and back up my files when my external hdd is inserted but it does not work.

First I entered in terminal the command `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb`

```
looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3':
KERNELS=="3-3"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
DRIVERS=="usb"
ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="3202"
ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
ATTRS{configuration}==""
ATTRS{devnum}=="3"
ATTRS{devpath}=="3"
ATTRS{idProduct}=="0578"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="152d"
ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
ATTRS{manufacturer}=="JMicron"
ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
ATTRS{product}=="External Disk 3.0"
ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
ATTRS{serial}=="212355187228"
ATTRS{speed}=="480"
ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
ATTRS{urbnum}=="11622"
ATTRS{version}==" 2.10"
```

And I used the output to write my udev rule.
I created in `/etc/udev/rules.d` a file with the name `99-RsyncToUsb.rules` and I entered the following command
`ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="152d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0578", RUN+="/opt/sync_files_to_usb_disk.sh"`

the script `/opt/sync_files_to_usb_disk.sh` has the following configurations `-rwxr-xr-x.  1 unix unix       744 May  7 23:47 sync_files_to_usb_disk.sh`

but still doesn't happen when I connect the device.

And my Rsync command is the following `rsync -hvrstc --delete --exclude=".*/" --backup --backup-dir=Lost-Found --suffix=_dltdFile --times  --progress /home/unix /run/media/unix/ExtDisk_1`

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution after some search.

First of all, in udev rules is necessary to add `ATTR{partition}=="1"` to avoid multiply calls of the script.

The second and the most important, in the called script, I had a syntax error `#/bin/bash` is wrong, the correct is `#!/bin/bash`